# Cannot scale to (0, 0) a <div> that has been transform: translate();

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I’m building a jQuery sorting plugin like [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) and I’ve come across a problem that is messing with the entire script.

In short: I need to be able to `transform: scale(0, 0);` a `<div>` that has been previously `transform: translate(Xpx, Ypx);` but the `<div>` keeps going back before hiding immediately.

I’ve narrowed it down to [a JSFiddle that easily reproduces the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/t2k0jedk/).

**jQuery**:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var applyTransform = function($box, value) {
        $box.css({
            '-webkit-transform': value,
            '-moz-transform': value,
            '-o-transform': value,
            '-ms-transform': value,
            'transform': value
        });        
    };

    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var boxId = $(this).data('box')
            , action = $(this).data('action')
            , value
        ;

        switch(action) {
            case 'translate':
                value = 'translate(200px, 100px)';
                break;
            case 'show':
                value = 'scale(1, 1)';
                break;
            case 'hide':
                value = 'scale(0, 0)';
                break;           
        }

        applyTransform($('#box-' + boxId), value);

    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="box" id="box-0">0</div>
<div class="box" id="box-1">1</div>
<div class="box" id="box-2">2</div>
<hr/>
<button data-action="translate" data-box="1">translate</button>
<button data-action="show" data-box="1">show</button>
<button data-action="hide" data-box="1">hide</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;

    -webkit-transition: all 1500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 1500ms ease;
    transition: all 1500ms ease;
}
```

You need to follow these steps:

1. Click `hide`: the `<div>`’s scale goes to 0
2. Click `show`: the `<div>` takes its initial scale
3. Click `translate`: the `<div>` moves away
4. Click `hide`: instead of hiding, the `<div>` takes its initial
   position and, wait for it, hides instantly.

I ensured that no external library, apart from jQuery, is loaded.

This is one of my first times playing with `transform` CSS property and I may have been missing something obvious but my research didn’t show anything up related.

Comment: You’re going to need to set both values: `transform: translate(…px, …px) scale(0,0)`.

Comment: @Xufox: That could be the obvious something I *may* have been missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@Xufox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816177/cannot-scale-to-0-0-a-div-that-has-been-transform-translate#comment51558069_31816177), I need to set both values at once, like so:

```
transform: translate(200px, 100px) scale(0,0);
```

Comment: Hey, how does this work if I would write it in the HTML code, instead of the CSS?

Comment: What do you mean by "*write it in the HTML code*"? Inline-style?